# Passing an object to another controller

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new to playframework.

So I have a class User with an object `user` and this is stored in another object called `userInfo`, and I want to pass this to the controller.

```
UserInfo userInfo = new UserInfo(user);
return redirect(routes.UserInfos.index(userInfo));
```

In my `routes` file, I clearly have

```
GET     /saveUserInfo      controllers.UserInfos.index(theUserInfo: UserInfo)
```

I keep getting an error that there is `no type UserInfo`.
The `routes` seems to be a simple text file. How do I add UserInfo as a dependency for that controller.index ?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.. I see your point but that should not be possible because routed action

```
`GET     /saveUserInfo      controllers.UserInfos.index(theUserInfo: UserInfo)`
```

would mean same that you are rendering page with url which has java object as parameter? that should be either JSON or something like Long type instead:

```
`GET     /saveUserInfo/:user_info_id      controllers.UserInfos.index(user_info_id: Long)`
```

But using that kind of Long it requires that it is already persisted to database so you could load it using Ebean or JPA at background to a view.

Got it? :)